# working with recordset on vba and access , how can I copy the last record and change a field of it

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I have my source data in a table call "MyData" where I can see how many products I have, and what type of product they are.

if the product is product type A I create only one compensation rule. However, if the product it is type B, I need to create two compensation rules.

I use more or less the following algorythm

```
rsrule=db.OpenRecordset("Rules", dbOpenTable)

Do While Not rsdd.EOF
rsrule.AddNew

Do stuff
Detect the type of the product
type="B"
flag= true 

rsrule.Update

now I want to add the same rule I have just added and change only one field rsrule![compensation percentage]=0.25

rsdd.MoveNext


Loop
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you have a 1 to many relationship between products and compensation rules.  Each product can have many compensation rules.  So structure the database accordingly:
[image]

The products table assigns 1 ProductID to each product in Stock.  the ProductTypes and CompensationRuleTypes tables have been added so the database can expand to handle new products and compensation rules.  The MyDataTable has no additional information so replace it with a form if the end user needs to do things like adding products and replace it with a report if the end user only needs to see the product counts.

Next it looks like you want vba code which fills the ProductCompensationRules table for all products.  This code also checks to see if the appropriate rules have already been added and skips them in that case:

```
Private Sub FillCompensationRulesTableUsingVBA()
Dim rsProducts As dao.Recordset
Set rsProducts = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Products", dbOpenDynaset)
Dim rsProductsCompensationRules As dao.Recordset
Set rsProductsCompensationRules = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ProductCompensationRules", dbOpenDynaset)
rsProducts.MoveFirst
Do While Not rsProducts.EOF 'loop through products and add compensation rule 2 for all products and compensation rule 1 for producttype 2
 If IsNull(DLookup("ProductID", "ProductCompensationRules", "ProductID = " & rsProducts!ProductID & " AND CompensationRuleID = 2")) Then
 With rsProductsCompensationRules
 .AddNew
 !ProductID = rsProducts!ProductID
 !CompensationRuleID = 2
 .Update
 End With
 End If
 If rsProducts!ProductTypeID = 2 Then
 If IsNull(DLookup("ProductID", "ProductCompensationRules", "ProductID = " & rsProducts!ProductID & " AND CompensationRuleID = 1")) Then
 With rsProductsCompensationRules
 .AddNew
 !ProductID = rsProducts!ProductID
 !CompensationRuleID = 1
 .Update
 End With
 End If
 End If
    rsProducts.MoveNext
Loop
'clean up
rsProducts.Close
rsProductsCompensationRules.Close
Set rsProducts = Nothing
Set rsProductsCompensationRules = Nothing
End Sub
```